# Method getLogger() no longer a member of Logger in log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have the `log4j-api-2.0.0.jar` and `log4j-core-2.0.2.jar` import into my build path. But somehow the following code were fail:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger;

public class TheClass {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TheClass.class);

...
```

And the error message shows that:

`The method getLogger(Class<TheClass>) is undefined for the type Logger`

I am just so curious is `getLogger()` no longer a valid method in Logger?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'll notice [`Logger`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html) no longer declares such a method.

log4j version 2 has made some drastic changes. [Here's](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/changelog.html) the change log. [`getLogger` seems to have been moved to a `LogManager` class.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-70)

[Here's](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) how they suggest making the migration.

Comment: And http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html might be useful to read too.

Comment: And you find tutorials no older than a year featuring guides for the old version. Beautiful.

Answer (score 12):

I'm giving an example for better understanding.

```
private static Logger logger;
        static {
            try {   
                   // you need to do something like below instaed of Logger.getLogger(....);
                    logger = LogManager.getLogger(ResourceService.class); 
              } catch (Throwable th) {
                    throw new HRException("Cannot load the log property file", th);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

with new Log4J 2, you have to add at least (in my case) log4j-core-2.8.2, log4j-api-2.8.2 and in some other case you may need to add also log4j-web-2.8.2.
So when you want to get a logging  you import
`import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;`

and finally the usage will be
`static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(WebService.class.getName());`

Note: don't forget to put config file into the root directory of the project, other wise you won't be able to get your logs.

Hope this will help someone
Kind regards

Answer (score 5):

If you are using log4j version 2.

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TheClass.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes your observation is correct.It does not support getLogger() method.

Check this Documentation link out: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html

Sample tutorial:http://www.javabeat.net/log4j-2-example/

Answer (score 2):

As noted in other answers, `Logger` is now an interface and you can get Logger instances from the `LogManager`.

API is now separate from the implementation, to give the team the freedom to change the implementation without breaking user code. The API will rarely change, and if it does change it will be in a 2.x version, not a 2.0.x version. That said, it is probably a good idea to always use matching log4j-api and log4j-core versions.

Answer (score 0):

To use the getLogger() method on your class, import the **Logger** class

`import java.util.logging.Logger;`

and use it as follows

```
public class SpringBoot {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getClass("SpringBoot");
}
```

And remember, this method takes a string argument.

Or Use **Logger from org.apache.log4j** package as seen below

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MessageProcessor {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MessageProcessor.class);

public void processMessage(Message<String> msg) {
    LOGGER.info("Message is about to be processed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class);
```